# Get HEX of Color constants in Android

Tags: java, android, colors

I searched and wasn't able to find the answer. What I am looking for is the HEX corresponding value for Color constants in Android.

For example:

```
Color.BLACK = #000000
Color.WHITE = #FFFFFF
```

So what would be the HEX values for the following constants:

```
    Color.CYAN
    Color.DKGRAY
    Color.GRAY
    Color.GREEN
    Color.LTGRAY
    Color.MAGENTA
    Color.RED
    Color.YELLOW
    Color.BLUE
```

Comment: [Google it](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm). These are everywhere, hex values for color are used in web design too.

Comment: You can also press `F3` on that code, that will display code of that value. :)

Comment: Check the [Android Color documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: Or better yet how do I add the background using XML. What is the XML version of Color.BLACK (e.g.)

Comment: In xml use @android:color/black

Comment: Just google it. You'll get what you want. Check this link: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/index.htm

Comment: Nice question.. But I have only one doubt, I have a color constant for ex : 17170449 which I need to convert into the hexa decimal code. is it possible? Thanks in advance @shree202

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK

> public static final int CYAN

Constant Value: -16711681 (0xff00ffff)

> public static final int DKGRAY

Constant Value: -12303292 (0xff444444)

```
public static final int GRAY
```

Constant Value: -7829368 (0xff888888)

> public static final int GREEN

Constant Value: -16711936 (0xff00ff00)

> public static final int LTGRAY

Constant Value: -3355444 (0xffcccccc)

> public static final int MAGENTA

Constant Value: -65281 (0xffff00ff)

> public static final int RED

Constant Value: -65536 (0xffff0000)

Comment: Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in your program code, then you can use the Color class.

```
Color.BLACK.getRGB();
```

Otherwise, just google it I suppose.